# Visual Studio This extension cannot be enabled because it depends on following disabled products: Microsoft BI Shared Components for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

After uninstalling both Microsoft Reporting Services Projects and Microsoft RDLC Report Designer extensions for a reason, a message box stopped me from enabling the first extension but the RDLC extension is enabled.

[Message Box Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT7c6.png)

So the message now is clear but what is the way to reach Microsoft BI Shared Components for Visual Studio and enable it.

I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run Visual Studio Installer

[image]

Choose the version of VS you want to to add the component to and click Modify.

Then click the "individual components" tab and search for "bi shared"

[image]